# Determining the bytesize of a row from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, automated-tests, size, datalength

I'm looking for a simpler way to determine the bytesize of a returned row from a query in SQL Server. I need this overall bytesize to debug a specific issue I'm running into.

For example, lets assume that I have the following query

```
SELECT 
COl1, 
COL2, 
COL3, 
COL4, 
COL5
FROM TABLEA
JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.COL1 = TABLEB.COL1
```

I've figured out that I can select the specific bytesizes of each column in the record with the `DATALENGTH()` function like this

```
SELECT 
DATALENGTH(COl1), 
DATALENGTH(COL2), 
DATALENGTH(COL3), 
DATALENGTH(COL4), 
DATALENGTH(COL5)
FROM TABLEA
```

And if I want to determine the overall length of the returned record, the datalengths can be added up like so

```
SELECT 
DATALENGTH(COl1)+ 
DATALENGTH(COL2)+ 
DATALENGTH(COL3)+ 
DATALENGTH(COL4)+ 
DATALENGTH(COL5)
FROM TABLEA
```

My issue is that the actual query is a little over two thousand columns, and some of the resulting columns consist of sub queries. The complexity would make converting the existing query to summing up the bytesizes a complex manual task that would be prone to user error, and would take a considerable amount of time.

Are there any good ways to convert the overall returned record into a bytesize for analysis?

Comment: Could you maybe insert the output into a temp table and check its size with sp_spaceused?

Comment: @Stu - Not if it is 2,000 columns

Comment: @Stu, thats an excellent idea, unfortunately it seems that the max columns in a temp table seems to be 1024 (based on the error I get)

Comment: Could you not break it into 2 queries and split the columns across each?

Comment: you could export the result in a text file and get the size of the file

Comment: What are you debugging exactly, i have very big doubts a bytesize of 2000 columns can tell you anything

Comment: @siggemannen You never know.  For example, years ago, I created a methodology to  allocate the cost of the Mainframe down to the individual cost centers based on the number of bytes used.   The line managers hated it, but they couldn't dispute the results.  :)

Comment: Wow, i figured you were from later generations :D It's curious though, two "datalength" questions in one day

Comment: 2000 columns seems to be the primary issue, there is almost certainly a data normalization problem here. I don't think I've ever written or needed a query that had more than 50 columns, and even that was with some reservation. Note that dynamic pivoting is meant for the presentation layer, it's incorrect to be trying that in SQL.

Comment: I don't even get out of bed for less than 100 columns, but otherwise i agree with @Charlieface, something is very wrong with your design

Comment: I'll let the data scientists know you guys don't like their design 
I've seen queries that hit the field limit, yet only ~20% of the selected fields actually get utilized ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

Not `datalength()` but this will give you total `len()` per record without having to list all of the columns.

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.Bytes
 From YourTable A  -- (or Your complex query) A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Bytes=sum(len(value)) 
               From  OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) 
             ) B
```